# GET /tasks does not work

Tags: java, asana, asana-api

I'm using Query Tasks method: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query using following code snipet:

```
    String url = API_BASE+"/tasks?completed_since=now";
    System.out.println(url);
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    httpget.addHeader( BasicScheme.authenticate(creds, "US-ASCII", false) );

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

**ERROR:**

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?completed_since=now
null
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:67)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:735)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:709)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:700)
```

Comment: Does the URL work if you pass it into the address bar of your browser?

Comment: Thanks, project is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Asana.

Yes, the underlying message from the server is:

"Must specify exactly one of project, tag, or assignee + workspace"

We'll take a look at updating the documentation for this since it does appear to be explicit with regards to this.

I highly recommend using url as indicated in the examples.

Also, we have a Java client library that you may find useful: https://github.com/Asana/java-asana

Thanks for bringing up the documentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like project is required parameter missing in documentation.